How do you query CMake for targets that include tests, from the terminal?
I have a test project here: https://github.com/ColinKennedy/example_cmake_ctest. It defines a driver executable called my_test_driver by autogenerating test_driver.c, which bundles some CMake tests together. The basic code for that looks like this
set(TEST_SOURCES test_a.c test_b.c)

create_test_sourcelist(TESTS test_driver.c ${TEST_SOURCES})
add_executable(my_test_driver test_driver.c ${TEST_SOURCES})

foreach(test_source ${TEST_SOURCES})
    get_filename_component(test_name ${test_source} NAME_WE)
    add_test(NAME ${test_name} COMMAND my_test_driver ${test_name})
endforeach()

My goal is to be able to define any arbitrary number of drivers like this and with an arbitrary number of tests. And to be able to create a tree that shows "which driver includes which tests".
So for this example, a tree could look like
- my_test_driver 
    - test_a
    - test_b

Another tree might have multiple test drivers and tests
- my_test_driver 
    - test_a
    - test_b
- another_test_driver 
    - test_1
    - test_2
    - test_3

I cannot assume that the user has the CMake project set up in a particular way. So another similar issue like like How to print all the properties of a target in cmake?, which require changes to the CMakeLists.txt, are not valid solutions to this question.
Here's How It Could Work
Each test driver has

A command to run the driver (e.g. an executable like my_test_driver)
A print-out that shows the tests that it can run.

If I can just solve the following questions below ...

Is target meant for CTest / testing? e.g. cmake --build build --target my_test_driver == 1. And cmake --build build --target not_a_test_target == 0
What is the command for a target. e.g. cmake --print-a-target-property my_test_driver COMMAND == ./build/tests/my_test_driver (the executable path)

If I have the above information then I can create the tree that I'm looking for myself. Any advice on how to solve those queries or possibly a different approach which can do the same thing?

I would use GoogleTest.
